# Why does High Sierra complain about IDLE?

Tags: python

I've installed an updated version of python 2.7, which comes with the IDLE development environment.

High Sierra is giving me warnings that it needs to be updated (which I took to mean that it's 32-bit, but it's not.)

I can't remember the exact warning, but it's the 'this app is not optimized for MacOS, consult the developer' thing.

Comment: Where did you install python from?

Comment: From www.python.org.

Comment: How are you starting idle?

Comment: @SteveChambers You can probably move your comment to an answer.

Comment: Please see my question. IDLE is NOT 32-bit, and isn't running as such, but I got the same warning in High Sierra as you get for 32-bit apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That specific error message means that the app (or a library, or launcher or component of some sort) is a 32 bit app and not a 64 bit app. **Something** in the Python installation is triggering that message even if python itself is 64bit.

And in an upcoming release of macOS 32bit apps will no longer work. Check python.org for FAQs/Discussions/Support/etc. for when it will be compiled as a 64bit app.

Comment: As you say, it must be some component of some sort, as the app itself is 64-bit.